# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, boolean

I'm so tired of seeing this error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_reorder_quantity, Line 16
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '–'.*

It states this because on line 16 where it states:

```
WHERE products.quantity_in_stock – products.reorder_level < @unit;
```

It's saying that `products.quantity_in_stock` is: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reorder_quantity
(
    @unit       int
)
AS
   SELECT
      products.product_id,
      suppliers.name,
      suppliers.address,
      suppliers.city,
      suppliers.province,
      'qty' = products.quantity_in_stock,
      products.reorder_level
   FROM
      suppliers
   INNER JOIN
      products ON suppliers.supplier_id = products.supplier_id
   WHERE
      products.quantity_in_stock – products.reorder_level < @unit;
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may just be auto-formatting messing things up, but `–` ("en dash", U+2013) is not the same character as `-` ("hyphen-minus", U+002D).

Try changing it to:

```
WHERE products.quantity_in_stock - products.reorder_level < @unit;
```

This is easier to see if I put them right next to eachother:

```
WHERE products.quantity_in_stock – products.reorder_level < @unit; -- yours
WHERE products.quantity_in_stock - products.reorder_level < @unit; -- fixed
```

Comment: Oh my. Yep that was it... I copied that line from an e-mail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always rephrase the line as:

```
WHERE                   products.quantity_in_stock < products.reorder_level + @unit;
```